# Contact photo not showing in Messages after update

Tags: messages, iphone, ios

I updated my iPhone 5 to iOS 10.2 and after the update my contact photos are not showing in Messages. Even the bubbles are not showing the contact photo just the name. What can I do?

Comment: That's not true because my wife and I have the same iPhone SE and hers displays them and mine does not. We are both up to date on our updates as well. So...

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been disabled in small screen iphones by apple. You can see photos only if you have iphone 6 or above